# Can someone help explain why this method for finding primes is so much faster than mine?

Tags: python, time, process, generator, primes

I have only started programming a few days ago and was trying to solve a problem involving primes up to a large number. Here is the method I came up with, but with large numbers it is slow:

```
import time
import math

t0=time.clock()

a=100000

##preprimes is the list of primes up to sqrt(a) that will be
##divided into the larger list lista


preprimes=[]

lista= list(range(1,a))
prelista= list(range(1,round(math.sqrt(a))))

def predivisors(a):
    x=a-1
    suma=0
    while (x>0):
        if a%x==0:
            suma=suma+x
            x=x-1
            if suma==1:
                preprimes.append(a)
        else:
            x=x-1          

for x in prelista:
    predivisors(x)


for n in preprimes:
    for num in lista:
        if num%n==0:
            lista.remove(num)

print(sum(lista)+sum(preprimes)-1 )
print(time.clock()-t0, ' seconds')
```

This method takes 81 seconds to return sum of primes up to 100 thousand. The following method I found online takes .38 seconds for the same task:

```
import math
import time

t0=time.clock()

n=100000

def getPrimes(n):
    """returns set of all primes below n"""
    non_primes = [j for j in range(4, n, 2)] # 2 covers all even numbers
    for i in range(3, n, 2):
        non_primes.extend([j for j in range(i*2, n, i)])
    return set([i for i in range(2, n)]) - set(non_primes)


def getCircularPrimes(n):
    primes = getPrimes(n)
    is_circ = []
    for prime in primes:

        prime_str = str(prime)
        iter_count = len(prime_str) - 1

        rotated_num = []
        while iter_count > 0:
            prime_str = prime_str[1:] + prime_str[:1]
            rotated_num.append(int(prime_str))
            iter_count -= 1

        if primes >= set(rotated_num):
            is_circ.append(prime)


    return len(is_circ)

print(sum(getPrimes(n)))
##print(sorted(getPrimes(n)))

print('process took ',time.clock()-t0,'seconds')
```

Why is this second method so much faster than mine? What factors determine how long a process will take?

Comment: I believe the second method is using the seive of erathos (sp?) which is pretty much the fastest way to calculate primes that Ive found(at least that I could implement) as an aside here is a neat hack ------> `isPrime = lambda n:~-2**n%n==1`

Comment: Note that the `getCircularPrimes` function is a red herring, it's not called anywhere and isn't used in the calculation of the primes.

Comment: I guess it's because of your remove function. when you use that function after deleting an element all the other elements after that would be shifted and it'll take time.

Comment: It's not sure it's obvious this is a dup, but it's the same question: we've got an implementation of trial division, an implementation of the sieve of Eratosthenes, and a question about why the former is algorithmically slower than the latter. Everything else is irrelevant here. But only if you actually know how to read the code. I _think_ that means that if this isn't a dup, it's not a question for SO and belongs at another SE site, but I could easily be convinced otherwise.

Comment: @JoranBeasley: The sieve is definitely not the fastest way to calculate primes. For huge primes, there are better algorithms (the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes#Prime_sieves) mentions some). And of course for smaller primes, a lookup table (or just a wheel up to N**.25) is the best solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your method you evaluate a list of `n` numbers against another large list of numbers based on `n`. 
In doing so you're performing a large amount of assignments

```
for n in preprimes:
    for num in lista:
        if num%n==0:
            lista.remove(num)
```

I believe this will lead to a time complexity somewhere in the `O(n^2)` range

> see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

In the online method I think it runs closer to a complexity of `O(n)`

The difference in runtime between `O(n)` and `O(n^2)` drastically rises as the input `n` grows.

Comment: can you briefly explain how the getPrimes(n) function works in the online code?